# React Native UI Freeze when upload to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, sdk

I've tried so many ways to fix this UI Freeze when reading file, blob or buffer from and request to s3

```
      // Set the configuration for the S3 client
  const configuration: S3ClientConfig = {
    region: s3Media.region,
    credentials: currentCredentials,
    useAccelerateEndpoint: true
  }
  const client = new S3Client(configuration)

  // const response = await fetch(asset.uri)

  // const blob = await response.blob()

  // await fetch(signedUrl, {
  //   method: 'PUT',
  //   body: blob
  // })

  const command = new PutObjectCommand({ Bucket: s3Media.bucket, Key: `${bucketId}/${filename}` })
  const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 })
  ReactNativeBlobUtil.fetch('PUT', signedUrl, {}, ReactNativeBlobUtil.wrap(asset.uri))
```

How can I solve this UI locking issue? JS FPS drops below 10fps and -2 fps cant navigate anywhere until it finishes uploading